# When a new component is inserted all the rest disappears inside the app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I always build my SPA apps with the vue-cli.

This time I'm building a small project and I'm incluing Vue with a script tag.

But I don't understand the following behavior.

```
// app.js

Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: `<div>Todo Component!</div>`
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue App!'
  }
})
```

The HTML index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app">

    {{ message }}

    <div>
      Just some content...
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is this:

[image]

Now, I'll try to add `'<todo-item />'` Component inside the HTML:

```
<div id="app">

    {{ message }}

    <todo-item />

    <div>
      Just some content...
    </div>

  </div>
```

The text 'Just some content...' disappeared:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

instead of `<todo-item/>` use `<todo-item></todo-item>`

Un-compiled vue.js does not support self-closing html tags.

see style guide:

> Unfortunately, HTML doesn’t allow custom elements to be self-closing -
> only official “void” elements. That’s why the strategy is only
> possible when Vue’s template compiler can reach the template before
> the DOM, then serve the DOM spec-compliant HTML.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

and issues in github:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8664